# Number each word with a randomly-colored number

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I place a number to the left of each word in my document, with each of the numbers being randomly-colored?

I have managed to number each word using the following code:

```
Sub IndividualMacros()
    Dim i&, w As Range
    For Each w In ActiveDocument.Words
        If w.Text Like "*[A-Z,a-z]*" Then
            i = i + 1
            w.InsertBefore i & " "
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But how can I change each number's color to be a random color?

Comment: Could you share more code? What is `ActiveDocument.Words`?

Comment: @LeopoldJoy `ActiveDocument.Words` is a collection within Word VBA ([MSDN documention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/words-object-word) describes the `Words` object as "A collection of words in a selection, range, or document. Each item in the Words collection is a Range object that represents one word.")

Comment: @LeopoldJoy, it is all my code:(

Comment: I've fixed the weird indentation, ...but why are you using a *type hint* instead of declaring `i As Long`? That said per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-insertbefore-method-word) after the text is inserted, `w` is expanded to include the new text, so it would seem that you need a second pass to color the numbers. As for the random color, certainly that's something you can research a bit? Your code doesn't even *try* to solve the problem...

Comment: @Mat'sMug, you are right. With my code i can solve only part of my task:(
And I need help to complete the second part of my program=)

Comment: research how to generate random values. ... record a macro of setting text to various colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

you will have to figure out the random number stuff

```
Option Explicit

Sub IndividualMacros()
    Dim i As Long, w As Range
    i = 1

    Dim aaa As Range
    For Each w In ActiveDocument.Words
        If w.Text Like "*[A-Z,a-z]*" Then
            w.Collapse wdCollapseStart     ' move pointer to before word
            w.InsertBefore i & " "         ' w range contains number and space
        '   w.select                       ' you can use this to see the range
            w.Font.Color = wdColorBlue     ' two ways to color text
            w.Font.ColorIndex = 4
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. Your program work perfectly!